# Non-Circular Proof of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm looking for a convincing proof, using first principles, that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$ (Please use ordinary unit circle definitions of trigonometric functions.)

It occurred to me that the classic proof, which compares three areas, uses the formula ${1\over 2}r^2\theta$ for the area of a circular sector of angle $\theta$, which in turn *assumes* the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$. But this fact is almost always proven in texts using an integral, which ends up using the derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and we're back to that limit again.

So I need a non-circular proof that doesn't rely on playing definition games ("let $\sin$ be the following power series..."). The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520622/non-circular-proof-of-lim-theta-to-0-frac-sin-theta-theta-1) is definitely playing definition games.

Sorry for the pun.

Comment: The formula for area does not require anything regarding sine and cosine; it suffices to have the perimeter formula $P = 2 \pi r$, which comes from the definition of $\pi$.

Comment: @Arthur but how do you know that $x < \tan(x)$?

Comment: It's tricky, because at heart, you need to know some deep properties about paths in the plane. For example, the distance $\sin x$ is the length of shortest path from $(\cos x,\sin x)$ to the $x$-axis, and the length $x$ is the length of a circle arc from $(\cos x,\sin x)$ to the $x$-axis, so we know $\sin x\leq x$. Then you can show with a similar, but more complicated theorem about paths, a bound that $x\leq \tan x$. Then show that $\cos x\to 1$.

Comment: I honestly do not think there is another way to get that limit other than the "staple-method" area inside circle - circle - area outside circle approach. I have reviewed many textbooks on elementary Calculus for our institution and always looked for a different approach on this topic. Nope, never found it. Remember though that the standard area method is generally easy "accessible" for students at this level. If there is another method that does not involve "circular logic", I would really like to know...

Comment: I don't think Archimedes used integrals for computing the area of circles and circular sectors.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to prove the area of a sector is $\frac{1}{2} r^2 \theta$ from within Euclidean geometry. And once you have that everything is straightforward (you draw the triangle inside the sector inside the other triangle and compare areas).

Comment: A way to start the proof (semi-formally): the circle is invariant under rotation. Therefore the area of a sector is the area of the circle, times the length of the arc swept out by the sector, divided by the circumference of the circle. Now by the definition of the radian, $r \theta$ is the length of the arc swept out. So now we need $\frac{1}{2} r^2 \theta = \frac{A r \theta}{C}$, i.e. we need $\frac{A}{C}=\frac{r}{2}$.

Comment: Hint: the area of the unit circle approximated by a regular $n$-gon is $\sin(2\pi/n)n/2$.

Comment: We can find the formula for the area of a circle by arguing that $\frac {d}{dr}A(r) = P(r) = 2 \pi r$.

Comment: The analysis approach - defining $\sin x$ as a power series, then proving it has a ton of properties, and finally that it must be your usual $\sin x$ - is perfectly non-circular. If it makes you happier, call the power series $s(x)$ and then prove that $s(x)=\sin(x)$. It's not the same as a the type of proof you are seeking, but it is non-circular.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: How can one prove from the power series of $\sin$  that it "must be" the "usual $\sin x$"?

Comment: That's the fun part, but it is a perfectly standard argument in analysis. Requires a few pages of work, though, so I'm not putting it here in comments. @user170039

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Can you then site some reference(s)?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Does the argument also entail the result that $\sin x$ is the ratio $\frac{\text{perpendicular}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. I've seen it done it books, but I'm away from my books.  It's a fairly standard argument. Usually best to start proving stuff about $\exp(z)$, then move from there. And yes, you ultimately prove that $s(x)$ is the same as that ratio of perpendicular to hypotenuse when $x$ is the length of the curve on the circle of the same angle. @user170039

Comment: One can use existence and uniqueness theorem of differential equations to show that $s(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: see similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1097757/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show that $x<\tan x$ when $0<x<\pi/2$ by taking the path:

$$(\cos 2x,\sin 2x),(1,\tan x),(1,0)$$

This path, aside from the endpoints, is outside the unit disk. The two segments are tangent to the circle. There is a theorem which says that therefore it has to be longer than the shortest arc on the boundary of the unit disk. I [asked a question about this a while back](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125975/shortest-paths-between-points-on-the-boundary-of-a-convex-set) - it is a result of the Hahn Banach theorem.

So this path, of length $2\tan x$, is greater than or equal to the path on the circle, $2x$.

(That $\sin x\leq x$ is due to a simpler rule - the shortest path from a point to a line, is the perpendicular from the point to the line.)

Comment: The Hahn Banach theorem certainly isn't needed in its full capacity.  What you really need is a line in $\Bbb R^2$ separating a point from a circle; perhaps this can be justified with good ol' Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Don't remember enough Euclidean geometry, though. It's certainly possible, I don't even know how Euclidean geometry deals with arc lengths rigorously.

Comment: That's a fair point... not sure how to do arc lengths myself.

Comment: Symmetry! This is a side-angle-side argument. If those points are $A,B,C$, respectively, then the triangles $COB$ and $AOB$ are congruent because the two sides are equal and the angle is equal. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: A nice thing in this picture is that the line segments lie tangent to the circle.

Comment: @TA Just saw it! Thanks

Comment: Right (the tangents) which you only actually know if you know the symmetry, too, because it is not obvious the first segment is tangent. If the segments weren't tangent, then they'd partly go inside the disc, and the argument falls apart.

Comment: Perhaps you can say that the arc is shorter than the line segments by an Archimedian limiting process.  In particular, take a "short cut" to make your two line segments into $3$, then add more sides to get a shorter path still which is closer to the circle, then claim that the length of the circle is the infimum of all such path lengths.

Comment: "Claim the length of the circle..." Well, that's sort of the question - why is it the infinimum? That's not usually how we define arc length. That assumes what we are trying to prove if we define the arc length as the infimum of all paths outside the circle. :) @Omnomnomnom First principles are hard.

Comment: any computation of $\pi$ based on its definition requires some definition of arclength, which is ultimately a limit.  It suffices then, to show that this limit is equal to whatever limit the arclength of a circle is defined to be.

Comment: But the limit is not, in any definition, an infimum. That is pecular to curves on a convex set's boundary, and paths that are external to that convex set. @Omnomnomnom Indeed, every definition of arc length uses **supremums** rather than limits, and definitely not infimums. Infimums are defined when talking about geodesics - shortest paths between $a,b$. So you are basically just assume the circle arc is a geodesic, not proving it is.

Comment: Fair point.  First principles are hard.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I like this approach. I think it gets to the heart of the matter. I was hoping for something simple, but probably there's no way around getting into analysis.

Comment: Interestingly, once you know this limit, you can easily show $(1+ix/n)^n$ converges to our expected $\cos x+i\sin x$. I'll link to that when I get home, if interested.

Comment: Basically, $\sin x/x\to 1$ and the easily derivable $(\cos x-1)/x\to 0$ means that for fixed $x$, $\cos(x/n)+i\sin(x/n) = 1+\frac{ix}{n} + o(1/n)$, and therefore, by the argument at the linked answer $\cos x+i\sin x=\lim (1+ix/n)^n$. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933

Comment: The approach which you mention to prove $x < \tan x$ is justified by a much simple theorem dealing with convex paths. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785841/72031

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything circular in comparing areas to get the inequality $\sin x < x < \tan x$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$. However we need to be very cautious in defining the symbols $\sin x, \tan x$ properly given $x$ a real number.

The approach based on areas goes like this. Using the concept of definite integrals it can be proven that a sector of a circle has an area. This does not require anything beyond the continuity of the function $\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$ in interval $[0, 1]$. In particular justification of the area of a circle is not dependent on the definition of trigonometric functions and $\pi$.

Next consider a unit circle with origin $O$ as center and let $A$ be the point $(1, 0)$. Let $P$ be any point on the circle. For our purposes it is sufficient to consider $P$ to be in first quadrant. Let the area of sector $AOP$ be $y$ so that $y > 0$. Also let $x = 2y$ and then **by definition the point $P$ is $(\cos x, \sin x)$.** This is the usual definition of trigonometric functions as studied at the age of 15 years or so.

Note that some textbooks base the definition of $\sin x, \cos x$ on the basis of length of arc $AP$ which is $x$. The definition is equivalent to the one based on areas of sectors, but comparing areas of figures is simpler than comparing the length of arcs (at least in this context). Consider the tangent $AT$ to unit circle at point $A$ such that $OPT$ is a line segment. Also let $PB$ be a perpendicular to $OA$ and $B$ is the foot of this perpendicular. Now it is easy to show that $$\text {area of }\Delta AOP < \text{ area of sector }AOP < \text{ area of }\Delta AOT$$ (because each region is contained in the next). However it is very difficult to compare the length of arc $AP$ with the length of line segments $PB$ and $AT$ (because there is no containment here).

The above inequality leads to $$\sin x < x < \tan x$$ from which we get $\sin x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and then $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}x} \to 1$. Further the inequality is equivalent to $$\cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$$ and hence $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

---

**Update**: It appears from OP's comments that the relation between length of an arc of a circle and area of corresponding sector is something which can't be proven without using any analytic properties of circular functions. However this is not the case.

Let $P = (a, b)$ be a point on unit circle $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ and let $A = (1, 0)$. For simplicity let's consider $P$ in first quadrant so that $a, b$ are positive. Then the length of arc $AP$ is given by $$L = \int_{a}^{1}\sqrt{1 + y'^{2}}\,dx = \int_{a}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ The area of the sector $AOP$ is given by $$A = \frac{ab}{2} + \int_{a}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx$$ We need to prove that $L = 2A$. We will do this using the fact that $b = \sqrt{1 - a^{2}}$ and using integration by parts.

We have
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx &= x\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - \int x\cdot\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}\,dx\notag\\
&= x\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - \int \frac{1 - x^{2} - 1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}\,dx\notag\\
&= x\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - \int \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx + \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}\,dx\notag\\
\Rightarrow \int\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx &= \frac{x\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}\notag\\
\end{align}
Hence $$\int_{a}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx = - \frac{a\sqrt{1 - a^{2}}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ or $$\int_{a}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}} = 2\left(\frac{ab}{2} + \int_{a}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx\right)$$ or $L = 2A$ which was to be proved.

Contrast the above proof of relation between length and area with the following totally non-rigorous proof. Let the length of arc $AP$ be $L$. Then the angle subtended by it at the center is also $L$ (definition of radian measure). Divide this angle into $n$ parts of measure $L/n$ each and then the area of sector $AOP$ is sum of areas of these $n$ sectors. If $n$ is large then area of each of these $n$ sectors can be approximated by area of the corresponding triangles and this area is $$\frac{1}{2}\sin (L/n)$$ so that the area of the whole sector $AOP$ is $(n/2)\sin(L/n)$. As $n \to \infty$ this becomes $L/2$ and here we need the analytic property of $\sin x$ namely $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Therefore area can't be the basis of a proof of this limit. This is perhaps the reason that proofs for limit formula $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ looks circular.

A proper proof can't be done without integrals as I have shown above. Hence the proof that $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ depends upon Riemann integration and definition of $\sin x, \cos x$ as inverses to the integrals. This is same as $e^{x}$ is defined as inverse to integral of $1/x$.

Also see [my another answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1001053/72031).

Comment: I have actually never seen this definition in terms of areas of sectors. Interesting proof.

Comment: How would you find the area of a circle?

Comment: @NotNotLogical: Area of a unit circle by definition is $$4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx$$ and if you may like, you can define $\pi$ by the equation $$\pi = 4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh These are those definition games I was talking about! :) Take $\pi$ to be the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter. How would you evaluate that integral? If you make a trig substitution, how do you know what the bounds are?

Comment: @NotNotLogical: So your definition of $\pi$ is ratio of circumference to the diameter. Great! by your definition $$\pi = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ and clearly you know that $$2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ so your definition of $\pi$ is same as my definition of $\pi$. there is no need to use any trig substitution.

Comment: @Ian: The definition based on arc length is common and perhaps more famous, but analytically more difficult to handle. I found the definition based on area in Hardy's classic "A Course of Pure Mathematics".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do you get between those two integrals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32773/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-notnotlogical).

Comment: @NotNotLogical: See updated answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Nice. I like your approach. I would do it a little differently, but the idea that I care about is that the area can be derived in terms of circumference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also note that (for small, positive $x$) we have $$\sin(x)<x<\tan(x)$$then divide through by $\sin(x)$ and squeeze. This gives the limit of $\frac{x}{\sin x}$.

Comment: but how do you know that $x < \tan(x)$?

Comment: Draw a triangle and a cord then it can be shown that the length of the arc < the height of the triangle.

Comment: @KayK. Obvious? Certainly not.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, my bad. I changed the word. Well, now I see it's not obvious.

Comment: What about this? $\tan 0 = 0, (\tan x)' > 1$

Comment: @KayK. That's basically circular, though.

Comment: That' requires you prove something about the derivatives of the trig functions, which usually starts with proving $\sin x/x\to 1$. @KayK. Anyway, "Draw a picture, it's obvious" doesn't really give the OP "convincing proof, using first principles."

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x$ is easy to define, but not $x$! You won't find a more elementary
rigorous definition of the $\sin$ function other that is the inverse of
the $\sin^{-1}$ function, where $\sin^{-1} y$ is defined for not too large
$y$ as the length of the arc in the circle between $(1, 0)$ and
$(\sqrt{(1-y^2)}, y)$. This is just the completely elementary definition
with the units for the angle actually defined.  It is not elementary
enough for a first course since it uses inverse functions.  The existence
of the arc length can be hand-waved and the coordinates not stated in a
first course.

Rigorously defining arc lengths needs a limit operation.  Fairly
elementary calculus gives the formula for the arc length of a circle:
$$\sin^{-1} y = \int ^y _0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)}}.$$  Note that
this is not circular; it is the definition of $\sin^{-1}$ and thus of
$\sin$.

The value of the limit is obvious from this formula using elementary
calculus.  Note that I haven't done anything complicated like evaluating
the integral.  Other properties of the $\sin$ function can be derived,
not so easily, from this definition.  $\pi$ is by definition the length
of a half-circle, and thus twice the value of this integral from $0$ to
$1$, whatever that may be.  Since the integral becomes improper at
$y = 1$, better define $\pi$ using half of the first quadrant instead
of all of it to minimize the calculus.

This is easier, at least for analysts, to understand after studying
elliptic functions and elliptic integrals.  Change $t^2$ to $t^3$ in
the integral and the integral becomes elliptic. There is no geometry of
the circle or arc length to help or confuse you in understanding this
integral. The inverse of the elliptic integral is an elliptic
(doubly periodic) function. This is much less easy to see and prove
rigorously from the integral than that $sin$ is singly periodic. Other properties of elliptic functions are even harder to see and prove
starting from the integral.

Comment: Try not to use exclamation marks after variable names if you don't mean factorials. If there is any reason to exclaim here, it is unclear, except that what you are saying is deliberately confusing. Of course, $x$ is easy to define, and what you mean is that $\sin x$ is hard to define because defining the arc of length $x$ on the circle is hard.

Comment: The geometric significance of the "$x$" in "$\sin(x)$" is what is difficult to define.