# Get parabola equation given two points and the path length

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, euler-lagrange-equation

How to find the parabola equation given two points and the length of the path between them?

Is it possible to solve it by euler lagrange equation?

Comment: You don't say if you refer to parabolas with vertical axis. If such is the case,  are you conscious that the family of parabolas passing through two fixed points is easily parametrized and that you will have evidently two solutions that do not need any lagrangian or so ?

Comment: Can you show how you do what you describe here? Thanks

Comment: I can do this but could you confirm that you deal with parabolas all with vertical axes  and not axes in any direction ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Please indicate asap how you proceeded to do this.

Comment: Voting to close, please show your attempts towards a solution asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the particular case of parabolas passing through points $A(-1,0)$ and $B(2,3)$.

Their general equation is:

$$y=f_m(x)=m(x^2-1)+(1-m)(x+1)\tag{1}$$

(see fig. 1). Please note that the form in (1) comes from a weighted sum  between one the parabolas (equation $y=f_1(x)=x^2-1$ and line $AB$: $f_0(x)=x+1$).

The length of parabolic arc AB along this curve is (classical formula)

$$L(m)=\int_{-1}^{2}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx=\int_{-1}^{2}\sqrt{1+(2mx+1-m)^2}dx$$

As one can see it on fig. 2, $L$ is an even function decreasing from $+\infty$, passing through a minimum when $m=0$ corresponding to the length of line segment $AB$ then increasing and tending to $+\infty$. Therefore in particular it will take twice the preassigned value you mention in your question.

[image]

*Fig. 1: Curve of some functions $f_m$ for $m=-1$ (top parabola) to $m=1$ (bottom parabola), with the particular case $m=0$ (line segment $AB$). Please note the overall symmetry of the figure with respect to point $(1/2,3/2)$ ; as a consequence, one cn restrict the study to values of $m \ge 0$.*

[image]

*Fig. 2: Even function $L$ with minimum value the length of line segment AB, i.e., $3 \sqrt{2} \approx 4.2426.$*

One could think that attempting an explicit computation of (1) could solve the problem. In fact, this is very tricky because there are different forms for the primitive function and no closed form expression for the reciprocal function.

Remark: one can also refer, on the side of intuition, to a result for convex functions : no shorter path exists by following a curve below a convex function between two given points ([Result needed: outside curve longer than convex inside curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734063)).

Comment: But how can one find m given the length L?

Comment: The partial answer is that using the curve in Fig. 2, you can retrieve two **approximate** values of $m$ for a given value of the length $L$... It seems that obtaining an explicit expression is out of reach...

Comment: ... but one can elaborate formulas giving very good approximate values of $m$ given $L$... Besides, I have attempted to ameliorate a little the presentation of my answer.