# Geometric proof that $\tan \alpha \geq \alpha$ for any acute angle $\alpha$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, arc-length

For any acute angle $\alpha$, then $\tan \alpha \geq \alpha$.  Is it possible to prove this geometrically?

My work so far:

A rigorous proof requires defining a radian measure of angles: this can be done in one of two ways:

1. Arclength.  E.g. define a semicircle to be $\pi$, and the measure of angle to be the portion of the semicircle it spans.
2. Area.  E.g. define the area of a circle to be $\pi$, and the measure of angle to be its area compared to the area of a semicircle.

Using arclength seems simpler (although area may end up being more rigorous), so I'll start with that.

There is a similar identity $\sin \alpha \leq \alpha$.  This follows directly from the triangle inequality:
[image: Picture from https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/trig/sines.html]

$\overset\frown {BD} \geq BD \geq BC$.

I tried to do something with the tangent segment (not show on the diagram, but the segment from $D$ parallel to $BC$ until intersecting line $AB$), but was unable to prove this.

Comment: See for example my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536080/291201).

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151) might be of some help. Note inequality $(1)$.

Comment: Continue from your attempt "the segment from $D$ parallel to $BC$ until intersecting line $AB$". The area between such segment and centre $A$ is a right-angled triangle, and this right-angled triangle has a larger area than the sector $A\overset\frown {BD}$.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, that seems to work, thank you.  It uses of course the area definition.  Is there a way to prove this using the arclength definition (which seems more natural and basic to me)?

Comment: @SRobertJames FWIW the link in my first comment uses the arclength definition.

Comment: Draw your tangent segment at $D$ to intersect $AB$ in $F$. Draw another tangent at $B$ to intersect $DF$ in $G$. The length $BF$ (ie $\tan\alpha$) is greater than sum of lengths of $BG$ and $DG$ and this sum is greater than length of arc (ie $\alpha$). See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785841/72031